# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, can't figure why?

Tags: java, android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

i wrote this method:

```
public static Bitmap matrixToBitmap(int[][] slika)
     {

         int w = slika[0].length;
         int h = slika[1].length;

         Bitmap into = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
         for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
         {

             for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
             {
                 if(slika[x][y] < 128)
                     into.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLACK);
                 else
                     into.setPixel(x, y, Color.WHITE);

             }
         }

         return into;
     }
```

and when I call it inside my android app with an `int[454][454]` array, it says this in `Logcat`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=452; index=452
```

pointing at this line of `matrixToBitmap` method:

```
     if(slika[x][y] < 128)
```

Can someone figure why is it happening? Values for `w` and `h` become 454 and 454, just as they should be.

Comment: What are the bounds of array indices in relation to the length of the array?

Comment: Just a note: you should use `int w = slika.length;`, not `int w = slika[0].length;` As it is, `w` and `h` will always be the same, even if the dimensions of the array are not.

Comment: Your `w` should be `slika.length`, not `slika[0].length`

Comment: The error message says your assumption is not correct: it's not a int[454][454] if the message says length=452

Comment: Now i figured out that actually int[452][454] was passed, and i got confused with w and h values when debugging, which actually were 454 and 454, because of my mistake which your answers corrected! Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

error is here:

```
int w = slika[0].length;
int h = slika[1].length;
```

what happened is, you set up length of first row from your array to be `w`, and length of your second row to  be `h`

to make it work, change it to:

```
int w = slika.length;
int h = slika[0].length;
```

Comment: As per question, an array of size `int[454][454]` has been passed, which I doubt is correctly mentioned. And if question statement is true, then error log detail is not correct.

Comment: now i figured out that actually int[452][454] was passed, and i got confused with w and h values when debugging, which actually were 454 and 454, because of my mistake which this answer corrected!